# Issues installing Visual Studio 2005 SP1 in Windows 7 RC

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

When I try to install Visual Studio 2005 SP1 in Windows 7 RC my machine freezes or blue screens half way through.  Has anyone else had this issue?  If so, did you solve it?

Comment: What is the stop error (on the blue screen)?  Does the log file give any clues?

Comment: Is this on a physical machine or in a VM?

Comment: it's a physical machine.  by the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2008 (right now, in fact) no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just chalking it up to the RC and removed it.  I don't need it right now, thanks anyway all.  Visual Studio 2008 works fine for now.

Comment: If Windows 7 is reporting it as incompatible, and VS2008 is compatible, then don't count on it working in the release.

Comment: I'm sure Microsoft will come up with a work around, it's a lot to ask if they want people to forget about 2005.

Answer (score 2):

A system freeze or blue screen (a.k.a. bug check) usually indicates a buggy device driver (which includes virus scanners and software firewalls) or failing hardware. (An overheating CPU or bad RAM can cause random data corruption, and it's even possible for a crashed hard disk to cause a bug check if the pagefile was located on that disk.)

If you post some of the text from the top of the blue screen, someone might be able to guess which one it is.

Comment: typically, yes, but this is specific to Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 0):

Without some more information about the stop error then there isn't a lot we can do to help you.

I would suggest you make sure all your background applications are stopped, especially if you shoe horned in some funky software that doesn't support Win 7 right (like Daemon Tools, etc.)  You may need to uninstall some things.

If that still doesn't work then try rolling back your drivers to the ones that installed by default with Windows 7.  If that doesn't work then try updating to the latest drivers offered by the individual hardware manufacturers.

**Edit**: Removed VS2008 reference.

Comment: wasn't he referring to Visual Studio 2005, though?

Comment: yes, I was talking about 2005

Comment: My bad.  Been looking at VS2008 so much I just assumed.  I removed the VS2008 reference.

Answer (score 0):

Does Windows 7 warn you that VS200**5** is incompatible?  I know it warns me on SQL Server 2008 as well as a lot of other older software.  If it does then follow the link for more information.

Comment: I did...hence the problem.